# How can "Constitution Council" be translated?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Context:

> Do you wish the **Constitution Council**'s proposals to form the basis of a new draft Constitution?

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_constitutional_referendum,_2012

I know that Constitution is "Verfassung", but how do you translate "Constitution Council"?

Comment: German answers are ok for me, I am German.

Comment: What is the Icelandic name for this council? Does it provide any hints? I guess the English name is just a translation itself, isn't it?

Comment: The most recent vaguely analog thing in Germany was called [Parlamentarischer Rat](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parlamentarischer_Rat). Before that, there was a [Verfassungskonvent](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verfassungskonvent_auf_Herrenchiemsee) (composed of experts, not elected representatives). Not sure if it helps.

Comment: It could be: Nationalrat, Verfassungsgericht, Verfassungsgerichtshof, Ratsversammlung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal translation would be

> Verfassungsrat

Comment: I don't think that is a good translation. I think it has to be something like "Verfassungsgebende Versammlung" oder "Verfassungsgebnde Vollversammlung". But I am not too sure about it.

Comment: @moose Well, that's what a "Rat" does (or can do). "Versammlung" would translate to assembly, which is used, too, but seemingly represents something else. And to use "verfassungsgebend" as an adjective for the Council might be misleading, since it has "completed its task" and "closed its office".

Comment: I second this translation. _Verfassungsrat_ in German is about as precise as Constiutional Council in English (or Conseil Constitutionel in French, for that matter, which does exist.) "Verfassungsgebende Versammlung" would be more than a translation: it's an explanation.

Comment: http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verfassungsrat I'm with @moose, except for the *Voll*.

Comment: It depends on the exact body, though. Der http://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conseil_constitutionnel_(France) ist nicht verfassungsgebend, im Gegensatz zur https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assemblée_constituante_islandaise_de_2011.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Interestingly, the English Wikipedia uses "convention".

Comment: I would like to know whether the Council is the same as the Assembly. It seems so because [each chapter](http://www.stjornlagathing.is/english/) seems to contain only one of them. That would match the German expressions, since it says on Wikipedia that "Verfassungsrat" can mean "Verfassunggebende Versammlung".

Answer (score -1):

I remember "verfassungsgebende Versammlung".

Answer (score -3):

I think the word, that you are looking for is "Verfassungsreferendum" or simply "Volksabstimmung"

Comment: Poster asks for the name of the group creating a constitution draft, not for the process to follow for acceptance.